# How to validate a form in ASP.NET using an image button, before raising the onClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

This may be a silly question but i'm a beginer here..

I created a form in asp.net and it's all fields are validated using validation controls on clicking an image button.It is working properly.After that i add an event to the button.This is the code of that button.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Clicked" ValidationGroup="AddSchoolValidationGroup" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/submit-btn.png" OnClientClick="submitClicked" />
```

The purpose of that event is for submitting all the values in the form to database.Here my problem is,After adding the onClick event to button, validation has not taken place.And i want these onClick event to raise only when the form is validated successfully.Can any one guide me ..Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you are using the same validation group for all the validation controls.
in addition you can use `OnClientClick` event to call validation.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Clicked" ValidationGroup="AddSchoolValidationGroup" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/submit-btn.png"  OnClientClick="return Page_ClientValidate('AddSchoolValidationGroup');"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript function

```
    function validateForm() {
        if (document.getElementById('txtName').value == '') 
         { 
             ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("rfvName"), true) // rfvName is id of validator
               return false; }
    }
```

and call that function on client click of image button

```
   <asp:ImageButton ID="Submit" runat="server" OnClientClick="validateForm();" OnClick="submit_Clicked" ValidationGroup="AddSchoolValidationGroup" CausesValidation="true" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/submit-btn.png" />
```

Comment: Thanks.But here i am using validation controls to validate.

Comment: You can enable/disable your validator controls from javascript.
e.g function validateForm()
{
 if (document.getElementById('txtName').value == '') {
  ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById("rfvName"), true)
  return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to validate the page before submitting. Please add attribute for button.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(Page_ClientValidate('AddSchoolValidationGroup')){return true;}else{return false;}");
}
```

Since you have a method "submitClicked" in onclient click, you can call the same inside Page_ClientValidate and remove the existing "OnClientClick" property.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(Page_ClientValidate('AddSchoolValidationGroup')){submitClicked(); return true;}else{return false;}");
}
```

Comment: Can u explain how to add this attribute to button?

Comment: You can add `Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:if(Page_ClientValidate('AddSchoolValidationGroup')){submitClicked(); return true;}else{return false;}");` in your Page_Load event.

Comment: is there any problem, the page contains more than one button with onClick event for different purpose.

Comment: onClick won't be an issue since it is server side event.

Comment: It haven't made any change.Check one thing,I am using image button instead of submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `OnClientClick="submitClicked"` with **`OnClientClick="return submitClicked();"`**

```
function submitClicked()
{
    if (document.getElementById('txtname') != '') {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert('Please Enter Name');
        return false;
    }
}
```

So until all the validations are validated, the Server side event will not be called.

Comment: Thaks for ur reply..But it haven't made any change.